# How to redirect back to the user edit page in Devise after skipping registrations in routes.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-invitable

I am using both devise and devise_invitable.

routes.rb:

```
devise_for :users, :skip => [:registrations]                                          
   as :user do
     get 'users/edit' => 'devise/registrations#edit', :as => 'edit_user_registration'    
     put 'users' => 'devise/registrations#update', :as => 'user_registration'            
   end
```

I did this change in my routes.rb, so now registered user could change password but new user can not register.
 The question is how should I custome the redirect after user edit their profile?

Solutions in this link https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Customize-the-redirect-after-a-user-edits-their-profile that devise gave me does not work for me in this situation.

**Edit**

The redirection is "127.0.0.1:3000/user.user"

Answer (score 0):

Try user instead of users in your as route

```
   as :user do
     get 'user/edit' => 'devise/registrations#edit', :as => 'edit_user_user_registration'    
     put 'user' => 'devise/registrations#update', :as => 'user_user_registration'            
   end
```

Comment: Edited answer. You may have to use user_user_registration.

Comment: I changed it in routes but it still going to the same place. Should I change something in view or controller ? The form view is : <%= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => user_registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>

Comment: run rake:routes. You should see something along the lines of user_user_registrations. Change :url => user_registration_path to user_user_registration_path.